# WPF Interleaving control z-order in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a control tree that looks sort of like this:

```
Canvas (or Grid -- any container)
    UserControl1 (or custom control)
        Green Polygon
        Red Polygon
    UserControl2
        Green Polygon
        Red Polygon
```

Is it possible for the child controls in `UserControl` and `UserControl2` to have interleaved z-ordering? For example, so that all Green Polygons are behind all Red Polygons.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Comment: No, this isn't possible. The attached property `ZIndex` only sets the Z-order with respect to other elements in the same `Panel`. Since your polygons are in different `Panels` this won't work.

Comment: @Meleak, you probably should convert that comment to an answer, since it's not only correct but also all the information required for an answer.

Comment: @AresAvatar: You are right, should have made it an answer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The attached property `Panel.ZIndex` only sets the Z-order with respect to other elements in the same Panel. Since your polygons are in different Panels this won't work.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Good to confirm it.